# Changes with drag and drop jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am currently in the process of conducting a system of drag-and-drop with jQuery. I have already started to create the base system.

I have tried with the function append() but it didn't work. If you have an idea, thank you.

I would like that when you select the item that it changes. For example, if I select a text when it is dropped it becomes a block.

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ov2p48u2/15/)

***HTML:***

```
<div class="drag">
    <p>Block 1</p>
</div>
<div class="drag">
    <p>Block 2</p>
</div>

<section id="drop">Drop here</section>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".drag").draggable({
    opacity: 0.7,
    snap: '#drop',
    snapTolerance: 10,
    cursor: "move",
    revert: "invalid",
    grid: [10, 10],
    helper: "clone"
});

$("#drop").droppable({
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var currenOffset = ui.offset;
        var dropedObjectCss = {
            "position": "absolute",
            "left": currenOffset.left,
            "top": currenOffset.top
        }
        var tag=ui.draggable;
        if (tag.data('alreadydropped')) {
            var newItem = tag.css(dropedObjectCss).appendTo( this );
            newItem.resizable({
                containment: "#drop"
            }); 
            newItem.draggable({
                opacity: 0.7,
                snap: '#drop',
                snapTolerance: 10,
                cursor: "move",
                grid: [10, 10],
                revert: "invalid"
            });       
        } else {
            var newItem = tag.clone().css(dropedObjectCss).appendTo( this );  
            newItem.data('alreadydropped', true).resizable({
                containment: "#drop"
            });
            newItem.data('alreadydropped', true).draggable({
                opacity: 0.7,
                snap: '#drop',
                snapTolerance: 10,
                cursor: "move",
                grid: [10, 10],
                revert: "invalid"
            });       
        }
    }
});
```